# Cocos2dx 3.3 Set header parameters for HttpRequest

Tags: cocos2d-x

I want to set some header parameters when submit POST request in Cocos2d-x 3.3
I did:

```
request->setUrl(url.c_str());
std::vector<std::string> headers;
headers.push_back("header_param1=123123");
headers.push_back("header_param1=abc");
request->setHeaders(headers);
request->setRequestType(HttpRequest::Type::POST);

std::string postData = "param1=aqweqw&param2=asdasd";
request->setRequestData(postData.c_str(), strlen(postData.c_str()));
```

But it was error, it seems my setting header params way is wrong.
Can anybody help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this way to add headers

headers.push_back(__String::createWithFormat("%s:%s","access-token",accesstoken.c_str())->getCString());

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem:

```
headers.push_back("header_param1:123123");
headers.push_back("header_param1:abc");
```

I must use ":" instead of "="

Comment: Then close the question please.

Comment: How can I close a question pls :)